# technique to create falling letters and words

Tags: javascript, css, html, objective-c-2.0

I'm looking for a technique to create a window with letters that drop from top to bottom, forming words as they go.

This is similar to the scroll screens used in the Apple Retail Stores.

What language(s) should I use? Are their techniques I can pluck?

Many thanks.

Comment: jQuery contains an animation library, which I'm sure can fit your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a wonderful resource that has been developed over the past ten years by a french programmer: Gerard Ferrandez. The site is http://www.dhteumeuleu.com/.

Specifically, Gerard's javascript technique to show falling letters is here:

http://www.dhteumeuleu.com/mistakes/

All of Gerard's work is open, and I urge anyone who uses this material, to contribute something.

Comment: I get a 404 with that mistakes link, but I found the one you were referring to https://codepen.io/ge1doot/pen/vNKYoP

Answer (score 2):

I'm not super-familiar with the system you are trying to immitate, but I found something that sounds like it might be useful to you after some tweaking. [Falling Text](http://james.padolsey.com/demos/falling-text/)