# How to add snow falling alphabets on html page

Tags: javascript, html

I want to have alphabets falling effect on one of my websites so please help me how can it be done. 
I need the effect as rainfall of letters

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5312123/technique-to-create-falling-letters-and-words

Comment: http://james.padolsey.com/demos/falling-text/ Can help.

Comment: need something similar to falling snowfall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this html code and see if that's what you're looking for.

```
 <marquee style="z-index:2;position:absolute;left:18px;top:97px;font-family:Cursive;font-size:14pt;color:#ffcc00;height:200px;"scrollamount="3" direction="down">Falling Text</marquee>
```

Answer (score 0):

have a look at css3 animations

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp

but you might have to include some JavaScript for multiple flakes